# Dynamic title in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, dynamic, title

How can I have a dynamic title of the map, which changes depending on the layer chosen? Is this doable? It would save a lot of time and iterations since I should be producing several maps.

To illustrate, I want the title to get the name of the first layer ticked if several layers are ticked. Any hint will be useful.

Comment: What version of ArcMap? There is a similar functionality to what you are looking for that is called Dynamic Text (Found under Insert->Dynamic Text Menu), but it does not look like an actual Layer Name is an option to pick. You could definitely do this with some custom Python programming though.

Comment: "first layer ticked", does this mean top most ticked layer in the layers table of contents?

Comment: ArcMap 10.2 Exactly, the top most ticked layer in the layers table of contents.

Answer (score 6):

Not fully dynamic, but in general this python code snippet will update a text element with the topmost layer name that is turned on in the defined dataframe:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0] # default Layers dataframe
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*", df):
     if lyr.visible == True:
          for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):
               if elm.text == 'Text': # whatever your text element is named here
                    elm.text = lyr.name
                    break
```

Comment: I run it but no title appears in the map. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: For this example, you have to create a text element in the layout which text = 'Text' (default).  This snippet does not create a text/title.

Comment: OK. I add a text element and I let the default text 'Text'. I run the tool and nothing happens. May be I am missing a step or? Your input is very much appreciated.

Comment: Make sure your text element in the layout does not have single quotes around it.

Comment: artwork21, could you explain further because neither that is working. I go to Insert-->Text. Then I run the script which is saved in a toolbox. It runs but nothing changes. The Text remains Text.

Comment: @dimitris the code needs an additional line to refresh the active view so that the text is updated. ... arcpy.RefreshActiveView()